# foreman with puppet 3 Could not find value for $confdir

Tags: puppet, theforeman

i cannot start foreman under puppet version 3

```
foreman/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:252:in `convert': Error converting value for param 'hostcert': Error converting value for param 'certdir': Error converting value for param 'ssldir': Could not find value for $confdir (Puppet::Settings::InterpolationError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:243:in `gsub'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:243:in `convert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:971:in `value'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:249:in `convert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:243:in `gsub'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:243:in `convert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:971:in `value'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:249:in `convert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:243:in `gsub'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:243:in `convert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:971:in `value'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:66:in `[]'
        from /usr/share/foreman/lib/foreman/default_settings/loader.rb:43:in `load'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.17/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
        from /usr/share/foreman/lib/foreman/default_settings/loader.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/share/foreman/config/initializers/foreman.rb:4
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:201
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:200
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/share/foreman/config/environment.rb:5
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /usr/share/foreman/config.ru:3
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from /usr/share/foreman/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /usr/share/foreman/config.ru:1
 failed!
```

i have applied all the workarounds from the below urls and still could not resolve it

http://theforeman.org/attachments/410/3_0-hack.patch
http://theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/PuppetThreeWorkarounds
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/foreman-users/QHyu-U7nE6Q
http://theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/Troubleshooting

below is my puppet.conf

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter
templatedir=/etc/puppet/templates
hostcert = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet.pem
certdir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs

[master]
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY

#reports
reports = http,store
reporturl = http://puppet:3000/reports
```

i tried manually adding confdir=/etc/puppet to the puppet.conf and still dint help

i have restarted all the foreman-proxy and puppet services and still no luck. appreciate any help to start foreman on this box.

puppet version 3.0.1,foreman version 1.0 on debian  2.6.32-5

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been making a few changes to squash this recently and have been updating the [PuppetThreeWorkarounds](http://theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/PuppetThreeWorkarounds) page that you mentioned.

With nightly packages from 6th December, or the 1.1 RC1, this issue should be resolved.